# Google plus button is not showing up

Tags: php, button, google-plus

I have used this code on my website for +1

```
<!-- Place this tag where you want the +1 button to render. -->
                <div class="g-plusone" data-size="tall"></div>

                <!-- Place this tag after the last +1 button tag. -->
                <script type="text/javascript">
                  (function() {
                    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
                    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
                    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
                  })();
                </script>
```

But it shows up only on on a pages without queries - for example
it shows up on index.php but it doesn't show up on index.php?id=1

Facebook and twitter buttons works fine.

How can I fix it ?

UPDATE
I've found a way how to fix it. The problem is that the button was showing up but it changed its style so the button was moved to the top, left ( -1000px ).

This solved my problem:
     
     `#___plusone_0, #___plusone_0 iframe {
     position:static !important;
     width:60px !important;
     height:70px !important;
     }`

Comment: Could you add a little more context? Whereabouts on the page are you including it? Does the Facebook button follow it immediately? Is there any PHP code in there? Does the javascript show up if you view the source code of the page?

Comment: Do you see it in the HTML source code on the pages it is failing to display the button?

Comment: You could post an answer for your own question?